# What is the "Regular Expression" for this given machine?

Tags: computation-theory, nfa

[Given Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubm4e.jpg)

Actually I'm confused between two options

1. cxa(bcxa+d)x
2. cxa(bc+d)x

here "x" means * on previous letter/bracket followed by "x".

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: both options seem wrong, since `x` is not used in the machine, so should never be present in the regex.  Also, can't have two consective `a`s, so a+ in wrong.  If you mean for `x` to really mean `*` then just use `*`, not `x`

Comment: @ChrisDodd He appears to be using x in place of the Kleene star. He may not understand the distinction fully.

Answer (score 0):

Write out our equations:

```
(q1) = (q1)c + (q2)b + e
(q2) = (q2)d + (q1)a
```

Simplify the expression for `(q1)` using the rule `(q) = (q)x + y <=> (q) = yx*`:

```
(q1) = ((q2)b + e)c*
(q2) = (q2)d + (q1)a
```

Replace the expression for `(q1)` into the expression for `(q2)`, factorize the `(q2)` out of the RHS, and apply the rule from above:

```
(q1) = ((q2)b + e)c*
(q2) = (q2)d + ((q2)b + e)c*a
     = (q2)d + (q2)bc*a + c*a
     = (q2)(d + bc*a) + c*a
     = (c*a)(d + bc*a)*
```

This appears to be what you have down for option 1.

Comment: `+` usually means on-or-more repeats in a regex context -- you should probably not use it if you mean `|`

Comment: @ChrisDodd Conventions differ, but + is the typical symbol used in theoretical sources I'm familiar with, and it's apparently the convention used in the question as well. I have seen the | convention and associate that more with applied regex implementations.